# Using Regex in Yahoo pipes to "clean" RSS feeds

Tags: regex, rss, feed, yahoo-pipes

Need some help in creating a Yahoo Pipe that strips certain elements from an rss feed. 
To clerify: I would use the regex code on Yahoo Pipes. I presume the regex syntax is universal?

I've broken the question up to some sub-questions:

1. What would be the regex for removing/striping a specific html tag (has its own class)?
   Content
2. How can I strip links from linked images but keep image markup?
3. How can I add sequential classes to all links found in a feed item? 
   If there are 5 links in a single feed item, they would be given classes: link001, link002, link003, link004, link005...

Due to new account limitation code examples can be found here:
[Using Regex in Yahoo pipes](http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/MQEIUaUBck)

Regex is not exactly my forte...  so any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression syntax certainly isn't universal.  See my [regex flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html).  Unfortunately the Yahoo Pipes docs don't say what regex flavor they use.  The examples look like Perl-style regexes, so that's what I'll use.

To remove a specific HTML tag (e.g. `span`) with a specific class attribute (e.g. `someclass`), search for:

```
(?si)<span[^<>]*class=["']?someclass["']?[^<>]*>(.*?)</span>
```

and replace with:

```
$1
```

The above regex will fail if the `span` tag you're trying to remove contains a nested `span` tag.

To delete any `a` tag that has an `img` tag as the first thing in its content, search for:

```
(?si)<a[^<>]*>(<img.*?)</a>
```

and replace with:

```
$1
```

The third item in your question cannot be done with regular expressions alone.  You'll need a facility to increment the number in the replacement.  I don't know if Yahoo Pipes supports something like that.  You don't really need a regex.  Simply search for the text `<a` and replace with `<a class="link001"`

Of course, all the caveats about manipulating HTML/XML with regular expressions apply.  The regexes work on the examples you gave, but they may not work as intended on every possible piece of HTML.